# Reading a String at an address from a core file in lldb with Python

Tags: python, lldb, coredump

I would like to read a string from an address in a core file using Python in lldb.  The catch is that I'm using a core file so there is no live process.

I can get to the string just fine by using normal lldb:

```
(lldb) p (char*)0x56039e6d71b0
(char *) $20 = 0x000056039e6d71b0 "nop"
(lldb)
```

The string I want is `"nop"`.  However, I can't seem to get to this string from lldb Python.

Here is what I've tried so far:

### Evaluate Expression

```
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression("(char*)0x56039e6d71b0").GetValue()
'0x000056039e6d71b0'
```

### Creating an address and asking for the value:

```
>>> addr = lldb.SBAddress(0x56039e6d71b0, lldb.target)
>>> char = lldb.target.GetBasicType(lldb.eBasicTypeChar)
>>> val  = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("name", addr, char.GetPointerType())
>>> val.GetSummary()
>>> val.GetValue()
>>> val.GetValueAsUnsigned()
0
```

### `process.ReadMemory`

```
>>> error = lldb.SBError()
>>> lldb.process.ReadMemory(0x56039e6d71b0, 3, error)
>>> error.Success()
False
>>> str(error)
'error: core file does not contain 0x56039e6d71b0'
>>>
```

I can't seem to figure out the right API to get this information in Python.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The API's you tried should work.  For the "EvaluateExpression" version, to see "nop" you want the summary, not the value.  The CreateValueFromAddress version also looks right.  But wait, how did `p (char *) 0x56039e6d71b0` work when lldb can't read memory at that address (as shown by the error from process.ReadMemory)?  That doesn't make sense.  I think we're missing something here...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need this as a lldb.SBValue, you can just ask the process to read the C string from memory:

```
s = lldb.process.ReadCStringFromMemory(0x56039e6d71b0, 32, lldb.SBError());
```

If you want to create a SBValue, you almost had it right, just use AddressOf() and don't get the pointer type.  Using the interactive interpreter we can see what went wrong:

```
>>> addr = lldb.SBAddress(0x00007ffeefbff980, lldb.target)
>>> print(addr)
0x7ffeefbff980
>>> char = lldb.target.GetBasicType(lldb.eBasicTypeChar)
>>> val  = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("name", addr, char.GetPointerType())
>>> print(val)
(char *) name = 0x672f73726573552f ""
```

The way you did it, the address you specified was the address of the *pointer* and not of the data it points to. We can see that the pointer value is the string itself in this case since all hex values in the pointer are valid ASCII characters. To fix this, we just use the SBValue::AddressOf() operator to get the address of the character at the address we specified and it creates the right lldb.SBValue(). Note I also pass "char" as the type and I don't call GetPointerType() on it when specifying the type:

```
>>> val  = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("name", addr, char).AddressOf()
>>> print(val)
(char *) &name = 0x00007ffeefbff980 "/tmp/a.out"
```

The easiest way to do this and get a lldb.SBValue back is to let the expression parser just do it for you:

```
v = lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression('(const char *)0x00007ffeefbff980')
(const char *) $1 = 0x00007ffeefbff980 "/tmp/a.out"
```

Even with a core file this should work. Simple expressions can often be done without needing a live process if the IR for the expression can be easily interpreted. Simple casting and member access (x->y.z) often fall into this category.